# Disable Right Click for OS X Webview

Tags: macos, webview

I put together a basic OS X app that has a webview that fills the entire window and loads a local web page with some text and images. Right now if the user right clicks one of the images they get a menu with the options to "Open Image in New Window", "Download Image", and "Copy Image".

Is there a way to easily disable right clicking on the webview?

Comment: can you subclass webView and intercept the right click event?

Answer (score 6):

Set the UIDelegate of your webview to an object, which should implement:

```
-(NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender 
    contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element
    defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems {
    return nil;
}
```

If you want to change the behavior for certain links, use the keys in `(NSDictionary *) element` to make your choice.

Comment: For future readers, UIWebView is now deprecated, but the new WKWebView does not have an equivalent feature.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to add this to the body tag of your HTML

```
oncontextmenu="return false"
```